# Chosen style is not working properly

Tags: jquery, dropbox, jquery-chosen

Here is my code:

```
      <select id="chosen" style="width: 200px;">
                                            <option>Choose...</option>
                                            <option>jQuery</option>
                                            <option selected="selected">MooTools</option>
                                            <option>Prototype</option>
                                            <option>Dojo Toolkit</option>
                                        </select>
```

but this is the result:
[image]

I have implemented plugin files like that:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
   <script type="stylesheet" src="~/Styles/chosen.css"> </script>
```

and also

`$("#chosen").chosen();`
Whats is my mistake? Could you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Link css like this

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="~/Styles/chosen.css">
```

Comment: not error. But I have warning like this:Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://...../~/Styles/chosen.css".

Comment: Is the folder Styles in the same place as the folder js?

Comment: now it s ok. I changed to path like this.<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../Styles/chosen.css">

Comment: Yes. It works.I supposed that your question js and css file are in the same folder. Root folder is the same yes:)